# Core Search only yielding results on specific words

Tags: 7, search

We've developed a lot of Drupal 7 websites, but never encountered this before (or just didn't notice). When searching the project in question (while having re-indexed the site untill the index is 100%) for a specific word like `met` it finds a basic page node which contains that word, perfect. Though when looking in the same node and trying the word `emissiespectograaf` we cannot find the same node nor any other. This goes for a lot of other words, long or short.

I'm just not getting it, it finds one word in a node but another word, which I know for sure that is in the same node, it's unable to find it. Even though the index has been built for 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit after hours of debugging, it seems that the module [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) is causing major issues with resetting the Drupal static. See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603578) which contains a temporary workaround patch, since this issue has not been resolved with a solid fix yet.